# The Xcode service is disabled on this server

Tags: xcode, crash, continuous-integration, osx-server

I'm trying to use OS X Server Xcode service integration.

In OS X Server, I'm sure to switch Xcode Service ON.

In Xcode Preference, Account tab, I select + and choose Add Server. I can see my Server appear in the list box. Then I fill the username and password, click Add, but the error "**The Xcode service is disabled on this server**" appear !!!

[image: The Xcode service is disabled on this server.]

Someone hints that I should use IP address instead of selecting the Server name when adding Server. This works, but I then have many problems when adding remote repository or creating bots. Either Xcode asks for certificate, or shows "Server is offline", or **crashes** (crashes frequently!), ... I think they all relate to the previous Adding Server process.

So how to deal with this ?

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing and I'm wondering if it's because the server and the client are on two separate subnets and/or not visible to each other via Bonjour.  I have an Xcode server at home that works fine with Xcode as a client when I'm at home.  However, I can't VPN to work and successfully use the Xcode server there.  I believe it's subnets ... I wish we had more configurability, but maybe there is via serveradmin on the command-line.

Comment: @GregCombs Hi, I have my OSX Server and Xcode on the same computer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Via the `OS X Server` app, click "Xcode" in the left sidebar and then make sure the Xcode "service" has been turned on via the slider at the top right:

[image: Enable Xcode Service]